# Inno Setup Disable Next Button if user does not replace 'Enter' with anything else

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How do I prevent user from moving on if `'Enter'` is not overwritten with anything else. Instead of `'Enter'`, I can also just make it blank. Regardless, the user must put something in there in order to enable the Next button. This is the second window after the welcome page that I need to do this with.

```pascal
[Code]

var
  SettingEnv: TInputQueryWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  SettingEnv := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
    'User Input', '', 'Enter SettingEnv, then click Next.');
  SettingEnv.Add('', False);
  SettingEnv.Values[0] := 'Enter';
end;
```

Comment: See [Inno Setup Disable Next button when input is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35837765/850848), You just need an opposite condition. So instead `(CompareText(Page.Values[0], 'Admin') = 0)`, use `(CompareText(SettingEnv.Values[0], 'Enter') <> 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use:

```
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
```

From the [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents):

> Called when the user clicks the **Next** button. If you return `True`,
>   the wizard will move to the next page; if you return `False`, it will
>   remain on the **current page** (specified by `CurPageID`).
>
> Note that this function is called on silent installs as well, even
>   though there is no Next button that the user can click. Setup instead
>   simulates "clicks" on the Next button. On a silent install, if your
>   `NextButtonClick` function returns False prior to installation starting,
>   Setup will exit automatically.

There is a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274569/how-to-disable-next-button-if-no-component-is-selected-in-inno-setup/37278700#37278700) to a similar question which has code. This will help.